# How to catch event when EditText is filled and new key is pressed?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keypress

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapCharacters"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:hint="ABC"
    />
```

Also have another `EditText` that should be focused when all 3 symbols are filled in the `name`.

```
name.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        // Move to surname when all three symbols are entered.
        if (name.text.toString().length == 3) {
            surname.requestFocus()
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }
})
```

It works right when we enter 1, 2 and 3 symbols. But when we select last position in `name`, press a new letter in a keyboard, nothing happens. I tried to catch a key press with

```
name.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
    if (name.text.getText().length == 3) {
        surname.requestFocus()
    }
    false
}
```

but an event doesn't arise. How to move focus?

Comment: Can you elaborate this please: `we select last position in name`

Comment: Instead of `.length == 3)` try this: `.length >= 3)`

Comment: @UmangBurman, I mean, we have an EditText `name` = "QWE", then we touch a screen just after `E`, so that cursor stands right from `E`.

Comment: Oh okay, where do you want it to be?

Comment: @UmangBurman. When we manually stand after the third position, I want to press "R" on a keyboard and focus a `surname` EditText.

Comment: Okay, did you try this: **Instead of .length == 3) try this: .length >= 3)**

Comment: @UmangBurman, I tried, but with `maxLength=3` the `EditText` consumes new events.

Comment: Try writing your code from `afterTextChanged` to `onTextChanged` Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `maxLength` to 4

`android:maxLength="4"`

In `afterTextChanged` :

```
 override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    // Move to surname when all three symbols are entered.
    if (name.isFocused() && name.text.toString().length > 3) {
        surname.requestFocus();
        name.setText(s.toString().substring(0,3));

    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but this is kind of a hack.

Comment: Agree with you, I am already experimenting with it. It has many traps but looks functional.

Comment: @UmangBurman Yeah but when you set maxLength to 3, you don't receive callback after that. So i don't any other workaround

Comment: @CoolMind you don't  need to set maxLength to 4 with this workaround

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was wrong. After reset will check again. :) I made a mistake writing `>= 3` instead of `> 3`.

Comment: no actually you are right.. but you can fix it by checking for focus.. I have edited the answer

Comment: so, when length is >3, you first change focus to `surname` and then `setText`. So the `if` condition will fail because `name.isFocused()` is false now.

Comment: I added my answer in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check in the beforeTextChanged() for if the char sequence is already 3 characters in length, if so then request focus on surname

Answer (score 0):

According to @nupadhyaya answer I made so.

1) Removed `android:maxLength="3"` (or can set `android:maxLength="4"`).

2) Added an event for new symbols:

```
name.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        val text = name.text.toString()
        if (text.length >= 3) {
            surname.requestFocus()
            if (text.length > 3) {
                // Remove symbols after third.
                name.setText(text.substring(0, 3))
            }
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }
    })
}
```

3) Added an event for `Backspace` key in surname:

```
surname.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, _ ->
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && surname.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
        // Move to the last symbol of name.
        name.requestFocus()
        name.setSelection(name.text.toString().length)
    }
    false
}
```